# Netsuite to salesforce integration Error in WSDL upload unable to parse

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying for the integration between salesforce na dNetsuite as an initial I tried to generate  the Apex classes based from WSDL when I try to upload the Netsuite WSDL had the following error. Do I need to make any changes to WSDL before I upload? Am I pointing to the correct wsdl for Netsuite?

Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Found schema import from location https://webservices.netsuite.com/xsd/platform/v2015_1_0/core.xsd. External schema import not supported.

Suitetalk wsdl link:

https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2015_1_0/netsuite.wsdl

Comment: The Apex class generation has many limitations - see e.g. [Supported WSDL Features](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm#supported_wsdls_topic-title). There are manual work arounds or alternate tools you could try; hopefully someone will post details of those.